# Is there a way to extract the origin coordinates out of a canvas in html?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

What I mean by that, is, let's say I have a 100 X 100 canvas, and I did `ctx.translate(50, 50)` on it. Is there a method or property I could access to retrieve it? Like `ctx.originCoordinates` or `ctx.getOriginCoordinates()` (In this example, I'd expect the value to be something like `[50, 50]`) I have a work-around, where I'll just manually update a variable every time I translate the canvas, but that feels like a very hacky/fragile way to do it, and if there is a better way, I'm all ears, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[`ctx.getTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getTransform) will return the matrix as a [`DOMMatrix`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix)

To get the translation use

```
const m = ctx.getTransform();
const translationX = m.e;
const translationY = m.f;
```

If the transform is uniform (that is Y axis is 90 deg from the x axis and x and y scale is the same then you can get rotation and scale with

```
const rotate = Math.atan2(m.b, m.a);
const scale = Math.hypot(m.a, m.b);
```

If there is non uniform scale then. Note only positive values

```
const scaleX = Math.hypot(m.a, m.b);
const scaleY = Math.hypot(m.c, m.d);
```

And if there is a skew then you can get the direction of both X and Y axis with

```
const rotateX = Math.atan2(m.b, m.a);
const rotateY = Math.atan2(m.d, m.c);
```

Note that you can use `rotateX` and `rotateY` to get the sign of the X and Y scale if needed

You can set the transform of one canvas from another

```
// set context A to the same transform as B
ctxA.setTransform(ctxB.getTransform());
```